# Circle Detection without use Aforge Or OpenCv

Tags: c#, image, opencv, image-processing, aforge

I want detect circles in bitmap without a library. First, i used otsu thresold for binarization. After binarization i used laplace edge detection. Now there is a circle in my bitmap. How can i detect this circle.

***NOTE: I tried to draw a circle and float x and y coordinates. But this way is so slowly and this way has   radius issue. Because, if my tempCircle's radius=10 and real circle's radius=9 then my algorithm can not find the circle.***

```
    BitmapProcess bmpPro = new BitmapProcess((Bitmap)(pictureBox1.Image));
    bmpPro.LockBits();
    int black = 0, temp = 0,fixX=0,fixY=0;

    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
    Graphics g = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10);
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < pictureBox1.Image.Width - 1; a += 1)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < pictureBox1.Image.Height - 1; b++)
        {
            double radius = 10;

            temp = 0;
            for (double i = 0.0; i < 360.0; i += 1)
            {
                double angle = i * System.Math.PI / 180;
                x = (int)(a + radius * System.Math.Cos(angle));
                y = (int)(b + radius * System.Math.Sin(angle));
                Color aa = bmpPro.GetPixel(Math.Abs(x), Math.Abs(y));

                if (bmpPro.GetPixel(Math.Abs(x), Math.Abs(y))!=Color.Black) temp++;

            }
            if (temp > black)
            {
                black = temp;
                fixX = a;
                fixY = b;

            }

        }

    }
    g.DrawEllipse(pen,fixX,fixY,50,50);



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LockBitBitmap
{
    class BitmapProcess
    {
        public int b = 0;
        int TotalPixelLocked; 
        Bitmap source = null; //kaynak bmp
        IntPtr Iptr = IntPtr.Zero; //baslangıc adresi
        BitmapData bitmapData = null;

        public byte[] Pixels { get; set; }
        public int Depth { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }

        public BitmapProcess(Bitmap source)
        {
            this.source = source;  //bitmapı dısardan al
        }

        public void LockBits()
        {
            //resmin en ve boyunu al
            Width = source.Width;
            Height = source.Height;

            //kilit için rectangle olustur
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,Width,Height);

            //kaynak bitmap ın pixel formatını al
            Depth = System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(source.PixelFormat);

            //pixel basına bit sayısını bul(Bpp)
            if (Depth != 8 && Depth != 24 && Depth != 32)
            {
                return; //bit türü desteklenmiyor...
            }

            //bitmapı kilitle ve veriyi döndür...          
            bitmapData = source.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, source.PixelFormat);

            //kilitlenecek pixel sayısını al
            TotalPixelLocked = Math.Abs(bitmapData.Stride) * source.Height;

            //pixel verilerini tutmak için byte dizisi olustur
            int step = Depth / 8;
            Pixels = new byte[TotalPixelLocked * step];
            Iptr = bitmapData.Scan0;

            //verileri pointerden diziye aktar
            Marshal.Copy(Iptr, Pixels, 0, TotalPixelLocked);

        }

        public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
        {
            Color clr = Color.Empty; //boş renk

            //renkli nesne sayısını al
            int cCount = Depth / 8;

            //istenen pixelin baslangıc adresini bul
            int i = y * bitmapData.Stride + x * cCount;
            if (i > (Pixels.Length - cCount))
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index out of range ( dizi adresi geçersiz)");
            }
            if (Depth == 32) //r g b a
            {
                byte b = Pixels[i];
                byte g = Pixels[i + 1];
                byte r = Pixels[i + 2];
                byte a = Pixels[i + 3];
                clr = Color.FromArgb(a,r,g,b);
            }

            if (Depth == 24) //r g b 
            {
                byte b = Pixels[i];
                byte g = Pixels[i + 1];
                byte r = Pixels[i + 2];
                clr = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
            }

            if (Depth == 8) // r g b hepsi aynı
            {
                byte c = Pixels[i];
                clr = Color.FromArgb(c,c,c);
            }


            return clr;

        }

        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
        {
            // renkli nesne sayısı
            int cCount = Depth / 8;

            // baslangıc indexini bul
            //int i = ((y * Width) + x) * cCount;
            int i = y * bitmapData.Stride + x * cCount;
            if (i > (Pixels.Length - cCount))
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index out of range ( dizi adresi geçersiz)");
            }
            if (Depth == 32) // r,g,b, (alpha)
            {
                Pixels[i] = color.B;
                Pixels[i + 1] = color.G;
                Pixels[i + 2] = color.R;
                Pixels[i + 3] = color.A;
            }
            if (Depth == 24) // r,g,b
            {
                Pixels[i] = color.B;
                Pixels[i + 1] = color.G;
                Pixels[i + 2] = color.R;
                b++;
            }
            if (Depth == 8)//r g b hepsi aynı
            {
                Pixels[i] = color.B;
            }
        }

        public Bitmap giveBitmap()
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(Pixels, 0, Iptr, TotalPixelLocked);
            source.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            return source;
        }





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only a few circles in the image, I'd recommend using [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC).

Brief explanation: From your edge pixels, pick 3 points at random and [find the equation of the circle](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) that fits these points. Use this equation on all your remaining edge points to see how many of them lie on the circle i.e. how many satisfy the equation. Repeat this process N times (N can be decided based on various factors, including the number of edge points, the number of circles, etc.), and record the iteration with the highest number of inliers (points lying on the circle). The equation corresponding to this maximal iteration is your best fit circle.

If you have more than one circle in the image, repeat the above steps after deleting or masking out all points that have fit previously found circles.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a look at a paper written by Yonghong Xie and Qiang Ji "A NEW EFFICIENT ELLIPSE DETECTION METHOD". [link](http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/publications/dip/2002/ICPR2002/DATA/07_3_20.PDF)

I know it has ellipse in the title but as you for sure know a cricle is just very special ellipse ;).

Hint: Next step in your procesing should be **clustering** your edge pixels - this way you will know which pixels are creating an **object**. As we know objects have some **properties** and you should determine what object properties makes that object a circle - and then implement these properties-based filters in your code.